# Item in listview to be displayed in single line each

Tags: android, listview, text, line

I have created a simple listview and added a few items in it. I am trying to add really long text in each item. I want this text to be displayed in single line only. the text that does not fit should fade in the corners. I have seen this kind of list in samsung galaxy s but somehow I am not able to achieve this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a TextView to provide the layout for each item in your ListView, just add these 2 properties in your TextView's layout definition xml:

```
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:inputType="text"
```